# how can i make the video reload after changing the src?

Tags: javascript, video

hello everyone i want to make a script to reload a src of video and i write a code to change the src and it's working but after changing the src nothing happend the new src did't work so i tried to reload the src of video frame but didn't work too and this is the script

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1();">Click Me!</button>
                <video id='hls-video' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <source id="change-src" src='http://vtpii.net:8000/live/946108483118595/641391346746584/185.m3u8' title='480p' type='application/x-mpegURL'/>
                </video>
                <script>
                var myFP = fluidPlayer('hls-video',{layoutControls:{autoPlay:true,allowTheatre: true}});   
                function myFunction1() {
                document.getElementById("change-src").src = "http://livecdnh2.tvanywhere.ae/hls/mbc1/index.m3u8";
                document.getElementById("hls-video").reload();
                }  
                </script>
```

so how can i reload and make the new src working after click and thankyou

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<video>` tag has no `reload()` method. You can use `load()` & `play()` methods in combination to get the desired behaviour like this:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('hls-video');
var source = document.getElementById('change-src');

function myFunction1() {
  video.pause()
  source.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4');
  video.load();
  video.play();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1();">Click Me!</button>
<video id='hls-video' style="width: 100%; height: 90vh;" controls>
  <source id="change-src" src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' title='480p' type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Comment: it didn't work with me i tried on your code alot but nothing working

Comment: it's just changing the src only nothing working after that

Comment: yes it's working but it didn't work in my code and i know that from w3school and i tried to edit their code but nothing help

Comment: By "_didn't work_" do you mean videos are not playing? Have you checked if the video urls are correct or not? have you tried to change the video src with some dummy video source from online?

Comment: yes bro i see some m3u8 links and every src alone working when i put the code and first one is onpiing when i click it stoped and i tried to cut the code the function without new src it stoped the video so i don't know what's the proplem here buut the two src are playing good

Comment: Not sure what is the issue happening at your end. Can you update your code and add a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so that others can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @palash my links as m3u8 so we can't run here we need vlc to run and i think there is a proplem after changing the sre the same src you put the same src i used but with diffrent links aas m3u8